# Выполнение функции Javascript после загрузки файла с js, который подгружается динамически

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть файлы со скриптами (к примеру wow.js), которые я хочу подгружать динамически в зависимости от некоторых условий. Но получается что у меня не успевает загрузиться файл, и уже инициализируется функция из файла. Что дает ошибку `fn... is not defined`

Как правильно это решить? `$(document).readu()...` не работает, т.к файлы подгружаю по условию.

```js
var o = $('html');
if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
  include('js/wow.js'); // Подключает файл js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    new WOW().init();
  });
}
```

Comment: надо дать скрипту обработчик события load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```js
include(
  'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
  function () {
    // скрипт загрузился
    console.log($('div').text())
  }
)

// вторым аргументов можно передать ф-ю которая выполнится полсе выполнения скрипта
function include (src, onload) {
  var script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = src
  script.async = true
  script.onload = onload
  
  // добавляет в body
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

```html
<div>Привет!</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Более современный вариант: использовать [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), но не поддерживается в IE11.

```
var o = $('html');
if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
    createPromise('js/wow.js')
    .then(() => {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            new WOW().init();
        });
    });
}


function createPromise(ref){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let addedScript = document.createElement('script');
        addedScript.src = ref;
        addedScript.async = true;
        document.body.append(addedScript);
        addedScript.onload = resolve;
    });
}
```